# Proving a statement by using its converse.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

Suppose we have proved $Q \Rightarrow P$ with the help of $P \Rightarrow Q.$

In order to avoid circularity, we haven't used $Q \Rightarrow P$ to prove $P \Rightarrow Q$ --- that is, the truth of $P \Rightarrow Q$ is established independently of $Q \implies P.$

Thus, we have in our system $P \Rightarrow Q$ (independently) and $Q \Rightarrow P$ (with the help of its converse). Together, we have

$$P \Leftrightarrow Q$$

I suppose this should a fine proof technique, albeit a bit awkward at first glance.

What are your thoughts ? Please do leave a comment/answer on the validity of such method. Any elementary examples ? Thanks for your time in advance !

Comment: If you first have proved $P\implies Q$ and then with this result concluded $Q\implies P$, you have a valid proof for $P\iff Q$. I have no example in mind where this works (only using the first implication to show the second).

Comment: @Peter Yeah ! I mean it did anyway come out as a bit strange to me at first.  Thinking about circularity, is it this: Using A to prove B and also using B to prove A; in essence, when we begin to prove B, we invoke A whose truth itself depends on the truth of B ! Hence, it boils down to assuming B in the proof of B. Thus, assuming what one is trying to prove. That is circularity (seemingly to me)

Comment: You can of course not prove both implications at the same time , using the other. But you said, one was proven independently. And then, there is no problem. Note that $P$ and $Q$ can also be both false !

Comment: @Peter Sure ! that comment was just about the meaning of circularity in general, and not related to the above question, where one part was proven independently. Have a great day !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure!  Here is an example (admittedly completely contrived!) where this may work. Suppose you have as premises $A$, $A \to (P \to Q)$, and $(P \to Q) \leftrightarrow (Q \to P)$.

Then we can combine the first premises to get $P \to Q$, which can then be combined with the third premise to get $Q \to P$. Hence, between $P \to Q$ and $Q \to P$ we have $P \leftrightarrow Q$.

Comment: Great ! Your input would indeed be valuable here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4592287/modelling-circular-reasoning