# Modelling Circular Reasoning

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

I am trying to understand circular reasoning. Here's how I've tried to think about it.

Say we want to prove $B$ true. We can achieve this by $(1)$

$A \Rightarrow B$

$A$

$\therefore B$

But it could be that we have proved $A$ by $B$ --- that is, the truth of $A$ itself depends on the truth of $B.$ Thus, $A$ is to be deduced by the following: $(2)$

$B \Rightarrow A$

$B$

$\therefore A$

It seems clear that in $(1)$ when we invoke $A$ to prove $B,$ we are indeed, under the guise of $A,$ actually invoking $B$ which is demonstrated by $(2).$ In essence, we're ultimately assuming $B$ in the proof of $B.$

I think that helps me understand circularity and why we shouldn't be assuming what we are trying to prove and in general, making sure that all the previous theorems which we are using to prove a yet unproved theorem themselves do not depend on anything yet unproved.

What do you think ? Does this model capture circular reasoning ? Please do leave a comment. Thanks in advance !

Comment: Not sure what you are aiming at here.  For instance, it may be that we start by showing $A\implies B$, then prove that $A_1\implies A$ and that $A_2\implies A_1$ and so on until at some point you  require $B$ to demonstrate that $A_n\implies A_{n-1}$ for some $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this would be circular. In effect, you have made the following argument:

1. $B \ \text{Assumption}$
2. $B \to A \ \text{Assumption}$
3. $A \to B \ \text{Assumption}$
4. $A \ \text{from } 1, 2$
5. $B \ \text{from } 3, 4$

And so yes, the conclusion $B$ relies on the assumption $B$, which is the hallmark of circularity. Indeed, as @lulu points out in the comments, there could be much longer proof paths that go from $B$ to $B$, but as long as the conclusion is one of the ultimate premises, you are dealing with a circular argument.